# Запись массива в файл

Tags: php

```
if ($_POST['name'] and $POST['sav']) {
    $file = $POST['filer'];
    $data = $POST['sav'];
    $buff = substr($buff, 0, -1) . "\n";
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $buff       = mb_substr($buff, 0, -1) . "\n";
    $dataLength = count($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $dataLength; ++$i) {
        $buff .= $data[$i];
        if ($i != $dataLength - 1) {
            $buff .= ' ';
        }
    }
    $buff .= "\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $buff);
}
```

Так? Я правильно понял?

Comment: сериализация массива не подходит для вставки в файл?

Answer (score 4):

---

```
$dataLength = count($data);
for($i=0; $i<$dataLength; ++$i) {
     $buff .= $data[$i] . ' ';
}

// обрезаем последний пробел и добавляем переход на новую строку
$buff = substr($buff,0,-1) . "\n"; // Для кирилицы

// если вы работаете с utf
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$buff = mb_substr($buff,0,-1) . "\n";

// как вариант можно избежать необходимость substr полностью
$dataLength = count($data);
for($i=0; $i<$dataLength; ++$i) {
     $buff .= $data[$i];
     if($i != $dataLength - 1) {
          $buff .= ' ';
     }
}
$buff .= "\n";
```

---

```
// непосредственно запись строки в файл
file_put_contents($file, $buff, FILE_APPEND);
```

PS: Я в последнее время подобные данные храню в json что дает возможность в 1у строку кода записывать в файл и в 1 строку кода восстанавливать полноценные массивы из файла. Но это new-school :)

Если содержимое должно перезаписываться тогда простом уберите флаг FILE_APPEND при вызову `file_put_contents`

Comment: чёт не получается, файл не изменяется

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Нужно записать массив $data в массив $file или в физический файл?
Если в физический файл, то можно сделать так:

```
> $other_mass = serialize($data); //генерация значения
>     
>     $f = fopen($filename, 'w');    //открываем файл
>     fwrite($f, $other_mass);       // записываем в него сгенерированное значение
>     fclose($f);
```

Comment: массив записать в файл

Comment: Ну тогда смотри на мой код =)

Comment: хм, не работает, незнаю почему

Comment: Видимо у вас проблемы с формулированием вопроса, либо серьезные проблемы с мат.частю

Comment: Это вы кому?

Comment: да, это вы кому?

Comment: а кому это вы? :trollface:

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . 'log.php', serialize($data));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался вариантом:

```
file_put_contents($fileName, implode("\r\n", $userData))
```